# Excel Array Lookup Formula

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have two tables as below. For formulas, assume "ID1" is on cell A1 and one blank row between tables so "ID" is on cell A4.

```
ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4     ID_OF_MAXDATE
a    b    d    #N/A    formula_here

ID     DATE
a      1/1/2015
b      1/2/2015
e      1/3/2015
d      1/4/2015
g      1/5/2015
```

In the formula, I want the id of the max date if id's in that row. So in this case, out of a,b,d - the max date is d with 1/4/2015. So the I want the formula to output d.

I have the below so far but the #N/A throws it off. Without the N/A value, the below outputs the max date. However, I want the ID of the max date. And it should ignore N/A's in the range. Note, all ID's in table 1 will appear in table 2. But some id columns in table 1 may be N/A.

```
=MAX(IF(A2:D2=A7:A11,B7:B11))
```

Comment: Just to be clear, in table 2, a single ID will never appear more than once, right?

Comment: @rwilson right, in table two each ID only appears once. But the date can be the same for multiple id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much bigger and complex formula than expected, but it will take into account that a date can appear more than once in the data set. Be sure and enter with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**.

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(MATCH(A2:D2,$A$6:$A$10,0),""))>0,LOOKUP(REPT("Z",255),IF(MAX(IF(FREQUENCY(IFERROR(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(A2:D2),$A$6:$A$10,0),""),ROW($B$6:$B$10)-ROW($B$6)+1),$B$6:$B$10))=IF(FREQUENCY(IFERROR(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(A2:D2),$A$6:$A$10,0),0),ROW($B$6:$B$10)-ROW($B$6)+1),$B$6:$B$10),$A$6:$A$10)),"No Match Found")
```

I also put in some additional error handling. The formula will return "No Match Found" if it is unable to find a match.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I dont understand the formula but it still only works in some cases.

Comment: If you start with the same data as in the original post, then change a2:c2 to be b,d,e and change the b date to be 1/6/2015, the formula outputs e (should be b).

Comment: Hmm. It shows up as "b", when I do it. I added new image on the bottom of my answer. Do I have the data setup correctly as you suggested?

Comment: yes, not sure why i get e. can you try changing something...say change d to 1/10/2015. i double checked what you pasted and my data - it's the same but my formula shows e. e was right earlier but when i played around with dates and changed a2:c2 few times, the formula started giving me incorrect output.

Comment: Ah, I pasted the formula again in the answer.  I think the ranges were just off. It wasn't including row 6 in the range. If you want to come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85263/excel-talk I can help you out further.

Comment: ha! got it. can't do chat cos it's blocked at work but i think it works. can you give me a gist of the logic. then i can figure out the functions.

Comment: The formula first checks to see if there is an available answer based on the inputs. If there is none, it will return "No Matches Found". If it passes this test, it then goes on to find the position of all the matches and returns the dates ONLY for the matches. It then returns the max date along with the position(s) of the max date. If there are any ties (More than one letter have the same max date), the formula will return the letter that appears last in the data.

Comment: thanks, I'm breaking it down to figure it out. what is the point of `ROW($B$6:$B$10)-ROW($B$6)+1` isn't that always equal to 1 i.e. 6-6+1?

Comment: ROW($B$6:$B$10) creates an array of numbers. In this case {6,7,8,9,10}. By subtracting ROW($B$6) from this array, you get {0,1,2,3,4} and then when you add 1 you get {1,2,3,4,5} . Yes, you could save a step by just doing ROW($B$6:$B$10)-ROW($B$5), but it's a best practice with Excel users to write it the way I have here in the formula.

Comment: thanks, you asked me this earlier but what if table 2 has multiple rows with the same ID but the dates are different? I just thought of an edge case when that could happen (no need to change the formula - I just want to know what would happen in that case)

Comment: That match returns an array of {2;"";3;""}. The 2 and 3 are positions in the TABLE. ROW($B$6:$B$10)  returns the positions in the SPREADSHEET. By using ROW($B$6:$B$10)-ROW($B$6)+1, I am able to convert the positions in the spreadsheet to match all of the positions in the table. The FREQUENCY function then looks like FREQUENCY({2;"";3;""},{1,2,3,4,5}). FREQUENCY is a whole other monster to explain. I know your chat is blocked at work, but I can explain it further in a chat-room after you arrive home.

Comment: If there is a duplicate letter. The formula will only look at the first instance of the letter. So in the example in my answer, if you were to add "e" in A11 and 1/10/2015 in B11, the formula would still only return "b".

Comment: i googled frequency and see what you're doing. still was getting lost a bit so i tried this and it works on a couple examples - `=INDEX($A$6:$A$10,MATCH(MAX(IF(IFERROR(A2:D2,"")=$A$6:$A$10,$B$6:$B$10)),B6:B10,0))` can you see holes in this?

Comment: I went back to your formula. I figured out the logic but the edge case of duplicates was at the back of my mind so I posted it again. if you have time, appreciate the help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191943/excel-array-lookups

Answer (score 1):

Insert an "iferror". In the example above, change the formula to:

```
=MAX(IF(IFERROR(A2:D2,"")=A7:A11,B7:B11))
```

Comment: Great, this fixes the N/A issue but I need it to ouput the ID, not the date.

Comment: Sorry, did not see the last part of your question. Add an index-match combo: =INDEX(A5:B9,MATCH(MAX(IF(IFERROR(A2:D2,"")=A5:A9,B5:B9)),B5:B9),1)

Comment: this works. thanks! why do you use the "1" at the end? I usually use 0 in my index match formulas?

Comment: Actually, there seems to be a small bug somewhere. if you change A2:C2 to be a,e,b and in table 2, make the date for e as 1/4/2015. the formula outputs d, when d is not even in the row.

Comment: @Moosa. The "1" here refers to the column number of the INDEX function; however, the third parameter of the Match function, the "Match_Type", IS left blank here and is indeed setting the function to search for an approximate match. This is the reason "d" is being returned when you change A2:C2 to be "a", "e", "b".  You could add a zero to the  end of the match function to search for an exact match and it WOULD return "e" here as expected; however, that too wouldn't have reliable results when using other inputs in A2:C2.

Comment: @rwilson thanks for the explanation. What formula would you suggest?

Comment: I approached this problem differently and my formula is actually about 3 times bigger in size... For this reason, I was just holding out until user3476534 came back online to see where he would go from here with his formula. I can post my formula if you like though. It's definitely not pretty, but it will work.

Comment: @rwilson sure please post the formula. I just need something that works. Doesn't have to be short. I do need to be able to copy it down for multiple rows of id's though.

Comment: If rwilson's formula works below, I would use it. Repeating dates is a hard thing to compensate for. I would probably start writing custom functions in VBA to get the job done from here. I'm tempted to delete my answer as it doesn't fully address your situation. Let us know if rwilson's formula doesn't work and we can continue adjustments of either method.