# Excel Array Lookups

Tags: excel

I have an excel row with some id's. I want to look up the id's from the first table in the second table below and get the id with the max date. The output should only be from the id's that are in the row in table 1.

For reference, "ID1" is in cell A1 and "ID" is in cell A4.

I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057768/excel-array-lookup-formula/32063302?noredirect=1#comment52259742_32063302) but my requirements changed and wanted to post this again. @rwilson in the earlier post gave me a creative formula that worked but I did not indicate that there would be duplicates in table 2. In table 2 below, "b" appears twice but with different dates. The formula output for the sample row of data below should be "b" because it has the max date. I cannot sort the table in any way as I don't control it. I need to reference it to output the id with the latest date.

```
ID1    ID2    ID3    ID4    id of maxdate
b      a      c      #N/A   formula

ID  Date            
b   1/26/2015           
b   1/28/2015           
a   1/26/2015           
d   1/29/2015           
c   1/27/2015
```

**UPDATED SAMPLE DATA**
This data sample uses @Marc's formula below. The output should be b but it shows as d. The reason is that the index is based off of the max date. Since the max date appears in d, index outputs d by default. Is there a way to tell the index/match to only index/match on id's that appear in table 1?

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4     id of maxdate
b   a   c   #N/A    d (should be b)

ID  Date            
b   1/26/2015           
c   1/26/2015           
a   1/26/2015           
d   1/28/2015           
b   1/28/2015
```

For reference, table 1 starts at cell A1 and table 2 starts at cell A4. Here is the formula in cell E2.

`=INDEX($A$4:$A$9,MATCH(MAX(IF($A$4:$A$9=IFERROR(A2,""),$B$4:$B$9,0),IF($A$4:$A$9=IFERROR(B2,""),$B$4:$B$9,0),IF($A$4:$A$9=IFERROR(C2,""),$B$4:$B$9,0),IF($A$4:$A$9=IFERROR(D2,""),$B$4:$B$9,0)),$B$4:$B$9,0))`

**UPDATE #2**
Here is the output based on @XOR's formula. Here is a case where it doesn't work.

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4     id of maxdate
b   a   d   #N/A    b (should be a)

ID  Date            
b   1/26/2015           
c   2/26/2015           
a   1/31/2015           
d   1/29/2015           
b   1/30/2015
```

Comment: rwilson states that his solution will work if there are duplicate IDs in the column.  Not sure what else you need?

Comment: Is the first table has a maximum IDs inside? Lets say 4 as you wrote?

Comment: @gtwebb no it works for duplicate dates, not duplicate id's with diff dates

Comment: @pnuts maybe but I can't count on it

Comment: @Balinti the first table 1 id per column. in the example below there are 4 columns so those will be fixed. if an id doesn't exist, it'll show as n/a as col D shows here.

Comment: I've been pretty swamped at work. If you don't get an answer though, i will take a stab at it late tonight.

Comment: I can't remember. Regarding your ID numbers on row 2, does your actual table have four ID input cells? Or are there more possible input cells?

Comment: @rwilson there are 4 fixed id cells in row 2. so if some are blank, they show as n/a. max is 4 cells.

Comment: Oh ok. Marcs answer should work perfectly then. Previously, I was building the formula based on the fact that there could be a dynamic number of input cells.

Comment: @rwilson see updated post. I saw an answer from you last night but looks like you deleted it. could you post that again? or if you found a problem with it then never mind.

Comment: @moosa I saw the update, and my formula outputs the wrong answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:C2,A5:A9)),LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+(B5:B9=AGGREGATE(14,6,B5:B9/(COUNTIF(A2:C2,A5:A9)>0),1)))),A5:A9),"No Matching ID")`

By the way, you don't specify which should be preferred if two or more IDs share the maximum date and also appear within Table1?

Regards

Comment: Good point. Many thanks. Have added a clause to that effect. Cheers

Comment: If two or more id's share the same date in table 1, then either one is fine. Whatever the formula does by default. It's late here but I'll try this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @XOR_LX see updated data in post. Here is a case where the formula doesn't work. I don't fully understand the logic here but it seems that you are computing max date based on table 2. Can the max date be computed based on id's in table 1? That should fix it I think.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Apologies. Have corrected. Can you test?

Comment: The new formula works with the sample data I posted but If you change d to 2/29, the output is still a. Should be d since d is in table 1

Comment: There is no such date as 2/29/2015!!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

This should get you the answer, if entered as an Array Formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=INDEX($A$4:$A$8,MATCH(MAX(IF($A$4:$A$8=A2,$B$4:$B$8,0),IF($A$4:$A$8=B2,$B$4:$B$8,0),IF($A$4:$A$8=C2,$B$4:$B$8,0)),$B$4:$B$8,0))
```

It's based on repeating the following formula, which finds the max date for the entry in cell A2 (if entered as an array formula):

```
=MAX(IF($A$4:$A$8=A2,$B$4:$B$8,0))
```

Enter that with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (array formula).

Combine that a few times, and then do an `INDEX()`/`MATCH()` lookup, and you can get the ID.  You'll need to figure out how to handle equal max dates.

Comment: You are going to need some error handling for the #N/As

Comment: @Marc thanks, this worked. I added some error handling to it. I've used these functions before so understand the logic. one question - you find the max of each id in the row, then do a match on the date. what if the date appears on another id not in the row. it works but I don't understand how. for example, if I change the date for d to be 1/28, why doesn't the formula output d?

Answer (score 0):

I always use what I call a MAXAIF function. You can add this into a VBA module and use it in your spreadsheet.

```
Function MAXAIF(ByVal id As Range, ByVal Criteria_Range As Range, ByVal Lookup_Range As Range)
    Dim max
    Dim ct As Integer
    For ct = 1 To Criteria_Range.Cells.Count
        If Criteria_Range.Cells(ct, 1).Value = id.Value Then
            If max = Empty Then
                max = Lookup_Range.Cells(ct, 1).Value
            Else
                If max < Lookup_Range.Cells(ct, 1).Value Then
                    max = Lookup_Range.Cells(ct, 1).Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MAXAIF = max
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

Per feedback, apparently the need here is to return the id with the greatest date attached along with the date. The following is a function that will accommodate that. If the last parameter is set to true, it returns the id, whereas if set to false it returns the greatest date.

```
Function IdWithGreatestDate(ByVal id As Range, ByVal Criteria_Range As Range, ByVal Lookup_Range As Range, return_id As Boolean)
    Dim max
    Dim max_index
    Dim ct As Integer
    For Each cell In id
        For ct = 1 To Criteria_Range.Cells.Count
            If max = Empty Then
                max_index = ct
                max = Lookup_Range.Cells(ct, 1).Value
            Else
                If max < Lookup_Range.Cells(ct, 1).Value Then
                    max_index = ct
                    max = Lookup_Range.Cells(ct, 1).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If return_id Then
        IdWithGreatestDate = Criteria_Range(max_index, 1).Value
    Else
        IdWithGreatestDate = Lookup_Range(1, max_index).Value
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I added the module and in the spreadsheet `=MAXAIF(A2:D2,A5:A9,B5:B9)` but I get a #value error. how do I write the formula?

Comment: For yours it would be this in each cell under your table of ids. =MAXAIF(A$2,$A$5:$A$9,$B$5:$B$9), =MAXAIF(B$2,$A$5:$A$9,$B$5:$B$9), =MAXAIF(C$2,$A$5:$A$9,$B$5:$B$9) ... etc

Comment: I need it to accept the id's as an array, get the dates and output the id with the max date. the example below is just one row but I need to copy down the formula hundreds of rows

Comment: Try out the second function and that should work well for you.

Comment: Hi, Did you try this? I'm not able to get it to work. Can you try it with the dummy data above and paste the formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX()` and `IF()` function to find the max_date for each ID in columns ID1, ID2, ID3, ID3 then use `MAX()` again to find max_date among the 4 values

SELECT max_date for each ID (enter using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER):

```
{MAX(IF(A3:A100=H3,F3:F100))}
```

SELECT max_date among the 4 max_date:

```
{=MAX(MAX(IF(A3:A100=H3,F3:F100)),MAX(IF(A3:A100=I3,F3:F100)),MAX(IF(A3:A100=J3,F3:F100)),MAX(IF(A3:A100=K3,F3:F100)))}
```

Then use `MATCH() | INDEX()` function to find the ID that has the max_date

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(L3,F:F,0))
```

Comment: that doesnt work when the max date appears on another id in table 2. For example, in the sample data above, b has the max date of 1/28. What if d had a date of 1/28? d is not in table 1 so I don't want that as output.

Comment: It will still showing b because d doesn't appear in ID1 to ID4.
Basically, the max_date column will look up in table 1 the ID input in ID1 to ID 4 to find the max_date. If you need sample, I can email you.

Comment: ok, can you explain this a bit - I dont understand how it will not return d. Because if the max date is 1/28, the index match looks up 1/28 in table 2. if there are multiple values with the 1/28 date, index returns the last match by default. Where in the formula are you restricting the index to match only id's that are in table 1?

Comment: I don't want to post my email here but can you post the formula based on the cell references I have in the post. start table 1 in A1 and table 2 in A4

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. You're right about the match, just that it will return the first match by default instead of last match. (that's why when I change the date of d, it still correct because b appears before d). Till now I couldn't find a solution for this. Will follow this topic if there's any one can help to find out a solution. The above solution form Marc is he same as mine.